# Grails - controller access variables from gsp

Tags: grails, controller, gsp, parameters

I have the following grails controller

```
class UserController {

    def userService
    def roleService

    def index() { 
        def roles = roleService.listRoles()
        [roles: roles]
    }

    def userDetails() {
        [user: userService.getUser(params.id), role:params.role]
    }

    def updateUser() {
        def user = userService.getUser(params.id)
        if (!(params.username)) {
            flash.message = "You have to enter a username!"
            redirect(action: "userDetails")
        }
        else {
            user.username = params.username
            user.person.title = params.title
            user.person.given = params.given
            user.person.middle = params.middle
            user.person.family = params.family
            userService.updateUser(user)
            redirect(action: "index")
        }
    }
}
```

Starting with `index()` the user gets a list of all roles and users currently available. The user may then select one particular user being linked to the `userDetails()`-action. There I retrieve the information about the `id` of the user with `params.id` and the user's role name with `params.role`.

In `userDetails.gsp` the user is able to update some of the user's properties. However, if he doesn't enter a username, he should be redirected back to the `userDetails.gsp`. (I know that I could check this with the `required`-attribute within the gsp - it's just to understand the functionality)

And here is where I get stuck - when using the `userDetails()`-action, two parameters are passed to the gsp. But now when committing the redirect I don't know how to access this information. As a result, rendering the `userDetails.gsp` results in an error as the required information concerning the `user` and the `role` are not available.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the form (presumably) that submits to the `updateUser` action, so that it also sends in the role. Then if the data submitted is invalid, you simply include these parameters when redirecting back to the `userDetails` action.

```
def updateUser() {

    def user = userService.getUser(params.id)

    // I'm not sure if this the right way to get a Role from the role parameter
    // but presumably you can figure that out yourself
    def role = roleService.getRole(params.role)

    if (!(params.username)) {
        flash.message = "You have to enter a username!"
        redirect action: "userDetails", params: [id: params.id, role: params.role]
    }
}
```

As an aside, the way you're manually binding each parameter to the `user` object is unnecessarily verbose. [Grails' databinding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) can do this automatically.

Comment: It's working. Actually I had to put the following: `redirect action: "userDetails", params: [id: params.id, role: params.role]` in order to be able to retrieve the `params` in the `userDetails()`-action. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if `params` would work, I've updated my answer with your info